# OCMock test fails - expected method was not invoked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

IN test class

```
-(void)testMyTest
{
MasterViewController* masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];//[OCMockObject mockForClass:[MasterViewController class]];
id master = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[DetailViewController class]];
 [[master expect] getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
[masterVC doSomething];
 [master verify];
}
```

IN detailViewController

```
-(NSString*)getStringVal:(NSString*)param
{
NSString *returnParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-String",param];
return returnParam;
}
```

IN Master view controller

```
  -(void)doSomething
 {
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

[detail getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
NSString * returnVal = [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM2"];
NSLog(@"returnVal %@",returnVal);
NSLog(@"doSomething");
}
```

When I run the tests I get the following error:

> doSomething
>   Unknown.m:0: error: -[iOS5ExampleTests testMyTest] : OCMockObject[DetailViewController]: expected method was not invoked: getStringVal:@"PARAM"

It looks as if the method was not called. But if I set a breakpoint the the method, it stops and shows me that the line was executed by the application and I am also getting the logs properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getStringVal method gets invoked on the real object, as you have allocated new instance of DetailViewController inside doSomething method, it is not getting called on mocked object.

Instead you can do some modification in the doSomething method

```
-(void)doSomething:(DetailViewController *)detail
{
     [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
     NSString * returnVal = [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM2"];
     NSLog(@"returnVal %@",returnVal);
     NSLog(@"doSomething");
}
```

And in your test case

```
-(void)testMyTest
{
    MasterViewController* masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];//[OCMockObject mockForClass:[MasterViewController class]];
    id master = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[DetailViewController class]];
    [[master expect] getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
    [[master expect] getStringVal:@"PARAM2"];
    [masterVC doSomething:master];
    [master verify];
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Not working. now i am getting OCMockObject[DetailViewController]: unexpected method invoked: getStringVal:@"PARAM2"

Comment: did you add [[master expect] getStringVal:@"PARAM2"]; in your test case ?

Comment: You are calling NSString * returnVal = [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM2"]; in your doSomething method, so you need to add an expectation to that method in your test case.

Comment: I am doing OCMocktest for methods that will return some value. How to implement for void methods. Eg a method that calculates Simple interest. But it doesot return any value. How can check the calculation functionality?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29578/discussion-between-warrior-and-prasad-devadiga)

Answer (score 2):

Colud it be because your Master mock object is using its own details view controller instead of your mock details view controller?

```
-(void)testMyTest
{
MasterViewController* masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];//[OCMockObject mockForClass:[MasterViewController class]];
id detailVC = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[DetailViewController class]];

// This is the missing line. If you don't have such a property use setValue:forKey:
masterVC.detailViewController = detailVC

 [[master expect] getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
[masterVC doSomething];
 [master verify];
}


-(void)doSomething
{
    // This is the offending line: you should be using the mock object not a real one.
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM"];
    NSString * returnVal = [detail getStringVal:@"PARAM2"];
    NSLog(@"returnVal %@",returnVal);
    NSLog(@"doSomething");
}
```