# OCMock: A mock returns another mock but verify raises not invoked - why? how to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, ocmock

I have an iOS application written in swift but as required the mock tests are written in Objective-c (ocmock.org/swift/).

I have a utility class method that builds a CBLView (think an index) from a CBLDocument (think json).

I can perfectly mock out the (CBLDatabase) database and verify the interactions - perfect!

But I have a mocked method that returns another mock and I like to verify the interactions with that mock as well.

I'm gazing carefully at the fine OCMock documentation: http://ocmock.org/reference/

And browsed through the fine stackoverflow for example: [OCMock test fails - expected method was not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412472/ocmock-test-fails-expected-method-was-not-invoked)

When I run through the debugger it seems that the CBLView is not really mocked like the database at least the view object do is not wrapped with a `OCClassMockObject` like it is with the database object.

**Its still not clear to me how I mock a method that returns another mock that can be verified. Why? and how can I solve it?**

My class method looks roughly like this:

```
@objc
public class CouchUtils: NSObject, CouchUtilsProtocol {

    static func getView(
        database: CBLDatabase,
        designDocName: String,
        viewName: String
    ) -> CBLView? {

        let designDoc = database.existingDocumentWithID("_design/" + designDocName)
        ...

        let mapBlock = CBLView.compiler().compileMapFunction(mapSource!,
                                                             language: language!)
        ...
        let view = database.viewNamed(viewId)

        view.setMapBlock(mapBlock!, version: "1")


        return view
    }

}
```

My OCMock test looks as follow:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import <CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h>

#import "MyAppTests-Swift.h"
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"


@interface CouchUtilsTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation CouchUtilsTests

- (void)testGetView
{

    // 1. Mock

    id doc = OCMPartialMock([CBLDocument new]);

    NSString *mapFunction = @"function (doc) { if (typeof doc.type !== 'undefined') \
                              { emit(doc.type, {title: doc.title}); }; }";

    NSDictionary *all = @{@"language": @"javascript",
                          @"map": mapFunction };
    // niecetohave: have a reduce as well ~ in a seperate test case

    NSDictionary *properties = @{@"views": @{@"types": all}};
    OCMStub([doc properties]).andReturn(properties);

    id mockCBLView = OCMPartialMock([CBLView new]);
    OCMStub([mockCBLView createQuery]).andReturn(@"Query created");

    id mockDatabase = OCMPartialMock([CBLDatabase new]);
    OCMStub([mockDatabase existingDocumentWithID: @"_design/all"]).andReturn(doc);


    OCMStub([mockDatabase viewNamed: @"all/types"]).andReturn(mockCBLView);


    // 2. Run code under test

    id view = [CouchUtils getView: mockDatabase
                          designDocName: @"all"
                          viewName: @"types"];

    // 3. Verify expectations

    // fails
    OCMVerify([mockCBLView setMapBlock: [OCMArg any] version: @"1"]);

    // works
    OCMVerifyAll(mockDatabase);

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"Query created",
                          [view createQuery],
                          @"Must get a CBLView that can be queried");
}

@end
```